# URL rewrite overloading server memory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the web site

```
http://airportguide.com
```

That is on a VPS shared server and currently receives about 10,000 Page views per day.

Most of these pages are php pages with static URLs and I have recently performed an overhaul of the site and, as a result, have 10,000 mod rewrites (301) that I needed to add to my `.htaccess` file so I don't lose the traffic.

Since I have added those lines to the `.htaccess` file, my Apache server is spitting out server and memory overload errors.

I'm 99.9% sure it's because of the increased size of the `.htaccess` file which is now 1 MB.

My question is, is there another way to do these mod rewrites other than the `.htaccess` file that has to be loaded with each new page hit?

Comment: Here are a few of the rewrites. These are very straightforward static to static urls. I basically added another level in the directory path for the state/province of the airport. Do you see anything out of the ordinary here?                          `RewriteRule ^airport/Argentina/Laguna_De_Gomez-SA8C/(.*) http://airportguide.com/airport/Argentina/Buenos_Aires_Province/Laguna_de_Gomez-SA8C/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^airport/Mexico/Laguna_Del_Rey-MM82/(.*) http://airportguide.com/airport/Mexico/Coahuila/Laguna_Del_Rey-MM82/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Not sure why you say I'm not willing. There is no pattern to my rewrites as they are all unique. I am not masking anything in these rewrites as they are the physical directory paths to the 18 php files for each airport.  There are no passed variables or remanipulation of the URL to the real URL. This is why I was asking if there is a way to do this outside of an htaccess file. I would love to shrink down the htaccess but it can't be done with these names. If there is no other way, then maybe I need to abandon the static pages and create one dynamic one.